# What does a vector field $f(r,θ) = (1,1)$ look like in polar coordinates?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

What does a vector field $f(r,θ) = (1,1)$ look like in polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$?

I was having some difficulty understanding what this looks like because i'm not familiar with vectors in polar coordinates.

would it be like this, you can get to any point on the plane by selecting an r and a theta, then at that point would have an orgin of a vector of radius 1 and  angle 1 radian?  which would make the vector field a set up parallel lines??

Comment: By $(1,1)$ do you mean $e_r + e_\theta$ or do you mean $e_x+e_y$ or something else?

Comment: polar coordinates... not Cartesian.  In other words, (1,1) means that radius is length 1 and theta is length 1 radian for all points in the polar coordinates vector space... no matter what value of r or theta you pick as for vector.

Comment: The coordinates you're using doesn't necessarily reflect the basis you choose. If it did, then the 'coordinate basis' in polars doesn't strictly speaking consist of unit vectors.

Comment: You can pick any length for each of the component vectors.  this example just uses 1 to keep it simple.  anyways...there's something I have forgotten about polar vector fields ... was just trying to jog my memory...

Answer (score 2):

```
# Script Language: sagemath
#
#  it doesn't have a function to plot polar fields so i had to
#  create a wrappers to plot them using Cartesian vector fields.
x,y = var('x,y')

def f(x,y): 
    in_r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
    in_t = arctan2(y,x)

    out_r = 1
    out_t = 1 # angle measured from direction of r_in.

    x = out_r*cos(in_t + out_t)
    y = out_r*sin(in_t + out_t)
    return (x, y)

plot_vector_field(f(x,y), (x,-3,3), (y,-3,3), color='blue')
```

[image]